# Jags : RUNTIME ERROR: Cannot insert node into mu[1:30]. Dimension mismatch

Tags: r

I am trying to do a simple linear regression, using a normal distribution instead of a t distribution, but I keep on running into trouble. Does it have something to do with the standardization of the parameters?

I keep on getting the following error code:

```
Error in jags.model("TEMPmodel.txt", data = dataList, inits = initsList,  : 
RUNTIME ERROR:
Cannot insert node into mu[1:30]. Dimension mismatch
```

Here is the relevant data:

```
 if ( any( !is.finite(y) ) ) { stop("All y values must be finite.") }
 if ( any( !is.finite(x) ) ) { stop("All x values must be finite.") }
      Ntotal = length(y)
      # Specify the data in a list, for later shipment to JAGS:
      dataList = list(
        x = x ,
        y = y ,
        Ndata = nSubj ,
        meanY = mean(y) ,
        sdY = sd(y)
      )
```

This is how I load my data in:

```
source("HtWtDataGenerator.R")
HtWtData = HtWtDataGenerator( 30 , rndsd=5678 )
nSubj = NROW( HtWtData )
x = HtWtData[,"height"]
y = HtWtData[,"weight"]
```

Here are my chain initializations:

```
# INTIALIZE THE CHAINS.
# Initial values of MCMC chains based on data:
  mu = mean(y) 
  sigma = sd(y) 
  initsList = list( mu = mu , sigma = sigma )
```

Here is the model:

```
# THE MODEL.
modelString = "
  # Standardize the data:
  data {
    Ntotal <- length(y)
    xm <- mean(x)
    ym <- mean(y)
    xsd <- sd(x)
    ysd <- sd(y)
    for ( i in 1:length(y) ) {
      zx[i] <- ( x[i] - xm ) / xsd
      zy[i] <- ( y[i] - ym ) / ysd
    }
  }
  # Specify the model for standardized data:
  model {
    for ( i in 1:Ndata ) {
      zy[i] ~ dnorm( mu[i] , 1/zsigma^2 )
       mu[i] <- zbeta0 + zbeta1*zx[i]
       y[i] ~ dnorm( mu , 1/sigma^2  )
    }
    # Priors vague on standardized scale:
     zbeta0 ~ dnorm( 0 , 1/(10)^2 )  
     zbeta1 ~ dnorm( 0 , 1/(10)^2 )
     zsigma ~ dunif( 1.0E-3 , 1.0E+3 )
    # Transform to original scale:
     beta1 <- zbeta1 * ysd / xsd  
     beta0 <- zbeta0 * ysd  + ym - zbeta1 * xm * ysd / xsd 
     sigma <- zsigma * ysd
     mu ~ dnorm( ym , 1/(100*ysd)^2 )
     # sigma ~ dunif( sdY/1000 , sdY*1000 )
  }
  " # close quote for modelString
  # Write out modelString to a text file
  writeLines( modelString , con="TEMPmodel.txt" )
```

Where exactly am I going wrong? Does it have something to do with the chain initializations?

Comment: There's no `mu[i]`.

Comment: I get a different error code when I run : `mu[i] <- zbeta0 + zbeta1*zx[i]` it is - `RUNTIME ERROR:
Cannot insert node into mu[1:30]. Dimension mismatch`  @StéphaneLaurent